# Update MySQL table with button without refreshing page using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to update a value in a database without refreshing the page using `AJAX`.  I am completely new to `AJAX` but I have have managed to create a function after searching for answers on Stackoverflow but I am unable to make it work.

One the main page...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  function UpdateRecord(id)
  {
      jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "del_reason.php",
       data: 'id='+id,
       cache: false,
       success: function(response)
       {
         alert("Record successfully updated");
       }
     });
 }
</script>
```

The button (which is in a form)

```
<input type="button" name="delete_pos" value="Delete" class="delRow_pos"
       onClick="UpdateRecord(<? echo $row['reasonID']; ?>);"/>
```

The contents of `del_reason.php`

```
$var = @$_POST['id'] ;
$sql = "UPDATE gradeReason SET current = 0 WHERE reasonID = $var";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
//added for testing
echo 'var = '.$var;
```

The database connection is ok because other functions on the same page connecting to the database work fine and so do other jquery functions but when the button is clicked the alert says the record is upodated but it isn't

Comment: `$var = @$_POST['id'] ;` Why do you supress errors here? It might be useful.

Comment: there might be something wrong with the query execution part and since you are echoing the value of var, jQuery will always treat it as success and alert the success message. You might want to track the AJAX request/response using Firebug/Web Developer browser plugins.

Comment: @Shomz I didn't know I was, being new to AJAX I thought that was part of it

Comment: @Maximus2012 I have tried the same query with a literal id rather than echoing one while trying to troubleshoot and the result is the same

Comment: You are, because of the @ sign, remove it just in case.

Comment: @Shomz, thanks, you learn something everyday

Comment: what happens when you echo this query statement and run it against the database directly ? Does that give you the result that you need? If no then maybe something might be wrong with the query execution part. You should try to profile the code using network tab of firebug/web developer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412353/how-to-find-whether-ajax-request-successfully-send-by-fire-bug-add-on

Comment: Try running an example query (the one that gets generated) directly.

Comment: Just tried this quickly. The query is concatenated properly. You should change it to either use prepared statement (best practise) or at least force the id you receive to typecast to an integer to not leave this open to SQL injections.

Comment: `$var = (int)$_POST['id'];`

The query generated was: `UPDATE gradeReason SET current = 0 WHERE reasonID = 1337`

Any reason you cannot execute that manually? Should give you a hint.

Comment: I sussed it using Firebug, the del_reason.php needed to have it's own mysqli database connection, I thought it might use the one on main page but no.  As soon as I added the connect string it worked

Comment: Great :) Check my comment about the SQL injection part though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MySQL` query on the `del_reason.php` failed because it needed it's own `MySQLi` connection to the database.

As soon as I added it the script worked